# Can block device driver become char device driver

Tags: linux-device-driver, device-driver

New to linux device drivers. Just read the introduction about char and block device drivers. The difference that can be seen in between this two is in the way data is managed by kernel. Suppose, If I allow block device driver to manage 1 char at a time, does it becomes char device drive?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, Yes you can.
 But it doesn't serve the purpose. Block devices usually have a filesystem. So it's preferable to write a byte with the help of vfs rather writing directly. There is  a high probabilty you corrupt the block device.
Also the API set are different for both.